# How to Stop/Reset AnimationDrawable in Android

Tags: android-animation

Animation drawable is not "stopping".
I want to reset animation drawable when I click on the another button.

Code for starting animation drawable:

MainActivity:

```
private AnimationDrawable frameAnimation
iconConnecting.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation);
frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) iconConnecting.getBackground();
frameAnimation.start();
```

frame_animation.xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:oneshot="false">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/connecting0" android:duration="400" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/connecting1" android:duration="400" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/connecting2" android:duration="400" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/connecting3" android:duration="400" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/connecting4" android:duration="400" />
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

In frame_animation.xml, change **android:oneshot** value to true

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:oneshot="true">
```

[Documentation of android:oneshot](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#attr_android%3aoneshot):

> "If true, the animation will only run a single time and then stop. If false (the default), it will continually run, restarting at the first frame after the last has finished."